# JSONArray Loop in Ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I tried to loop a JSONArray in my js file, and I have failed.
Someone can help me please?
this is my servlet code:

```
ArrayList<Campionato> campionati = DBManager.getInstance().getCampionatoDao().query();

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(campionati);
    resp.getWriter().println(jsonArray);
```

and this is my Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url: "MyServlet",
    dataType : "json",
    success: function(data){        

    alert("lenght "+ data.length); //this work but if i try data[0] it say me undefined

    //I don't know what should I put here for looping

    },
    error : function(data) {

    }

});
```

thanks all!

Comment: Please clarify the question. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just have to loop jsonarray. Which is passed by Myservlet. I'm looking for but I can not find a solution, can you help me?
The date is a jsonArray

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet iterate over json array using JQuery

```
    data = $.parseJSON(data); 
    $.each(data, function(i, item) { 
        alert(item);
     }) ;
```

Comment: Ensure your data is json format or not. If it is already in json format then skip parsing json.Also check the format of json.

Comment: ok, thanks, but no work :( , i m sure that my data is json format

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what data is in function `success`.

Use `console.log(data)` or `alert(JSON.stringify(data))` to see it.

Comment: alert(JSON.stringify(data)) with this i see the memory address,["bean.Campionato@149fd83e","bean.Campionato@560ca2a0"]

Answer (score 0):

data in your response (`success: function(data){`) is an object, holding metadata and the data your expecting in its `data` property. So what you want to do is getting the actual data out of your response, and loop the array that it contains:

```
success: function(data){
    let d = data.data; // now d holds your response data - array
    for (let x of d) {
        console.log(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: same answer, not work, now i try to modify something in my servlet, maybe i wrong something in put my array in JSONArray

Answer (score 0):

Guys I realized what was wrong, how to put the data in the jsonarray.

the right way is

```
final JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    final JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

    try {
        for (final Campionato campionato : campionati) {

            final JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

            jsonObj.put("idCampionato", campionato.getIdCampionato());
            jsonObj.put("numPartecipanti", campionato.getNumPartecipanti());
            jsonObj.put("partecipantiTotali", campionato.getPartecipantiTotali());
            jsonObj.put("attivo", campionato.getAttivo());

            array.put(jsonObj);

        }

        obj.put("campionati", array);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    resp.setContentType("application/json");
    resp.getWriter().print(obj);
```

and in ajax

```
 $.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url: "provaServlet",
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(data){
        var campionati = data.campionati;
        var div = $('#cAttivi');
        div.empty();

        for (var i = 0, length = campionati.length; i < length; ++i) {
            var campionati = campionati[i];
            var stringToAppend = "<div> "+ campionati.idCampionato +"</div>";
            div.append(stringToAppend);
        }
```

now all works fine..

thanks all for your patience